# Many-to-Many mapping query spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to create an simple eCommerce using spring data.

I have 3 entities, Order, Products and a Many to Many table OrderProductRelation that contains OrderID, ProductID and the quantity of products requested.

I would like to know, how can I query OrderProductionRelation and map order and products into DTO to return something like this in my controller:

```
[
    {
        "orderName": "",
        "orderDate": "2023-07-29",
        "orderTime": "13:38:22.188871191",
        "totalPrice": 1706.25,
        "discounts": 25.0,
        "totalItems": null,
        "paymentMethod": "DEBIT",
        "orderStatus": "COMPLETED",
        "products": [
            {
                "productName": "mock 1",
                "productDescription": "new mock 1 shoe",
                "category": null,
                "quantity": 1,
                "brand": "mock1"
            }
]
```

Is there a specific way to do that ?

I'm currently using the findAll() method from OrderProductRelation repository and looping the query result, after that I turn each Order and Product entity into DTO so then each OrderDTO will have it's own ProductDTO list

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do that)

1. Use Spring Data JPA entity mapping + Hibernate ([example](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many))
2. Using Entity Graph (more advanced way - [example](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-graph)
3. More native way using JDBCTemplate and manually write select query with 1 inner join to order_product_relation and 2 to orders or products. ([example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/spring-jdbctemplate-example))

If you are a newbee in spring - i would highly recommend to use 1 approach, because its the simplest one, and once you face any problem (infinite select loops, N+1 problem, etc) - you just google them one by one, and soon you will become a pro in selecting data from DB)

1 Approach will allow you to query Products for example using ProductsRepository and automatically join all your Orders, then you just map it to DTO, and here you are.

Comment: I'm currently using Spring Data JPA, and I'm query the OrderProductRelation, getting Order and Product, and putting into a Map like Order:[Product1, Product2], then turning into DTOs but I don't know if it is a bad practice or if is there something already created by Spring Data itself

Comment: I’m sure it’s not a bad practice if you don’t have N+1 problem. Basically you have to try to make as less sql calls as possible.

Comment: So try to avoid situations where you are looping your SQL requests, other things - are much less important IMHO.

Comment: And turning your entities to DTOs before returning from server - it’s a Good practice.